# Calculating annualized continuous dividend yield

Tags: dividends

What would be a formula for calculating the annualized continuous dividend yield of a stock? 
Given the quarterly or annual dividend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$r=\ln(1+\frac{D}{S_o})$ where D is the annual dividend and $S_0$ is the current stock price$